# Помогите пожалуйста с кодом на C#. Microsoft.Office. Interop.Word

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

Дорогие друзья, помогите пожалуйста дополнить код, чтобы он работал корректно. На данный момент, когда я нажимаю на button у меня высвечивается word документ, в котором отображается бейджик сотрудник отдела, но он не совпадает с тем сотрудником, который у меня на форме, мне нужно, чтобы программа сама понимала какую именно открыть странницу с бейджиком сотрудника ориентируюсь на базу данных. Что мне нужно дополнить в коде, чтобы реализовать то, что я писала выше, помогите пожалуйста!!!!
Вот код:

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office. Interop.Word.Application();
var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"D:\бейджик.docx");
application.Visible = true;
document.SaveAs(FileName: @"D:\бейджик.docx");
```

ниже прикрепила скриншот на котором видно, что [image: введите сюда описание изображения]когда нажимаю на бейджики они не совпадают с сотрудниками на форме, помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: А как вы добавляете текст в документ? 
Попробуйте сделать шаблон документа, в шаблоне укажите поля, которые хотите менять из БД. 
затем через взаимодействие Word'а обращайтесь к этим полям в шаблоне.